# Windows symlink to user documents dir issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, symbolic-link

I'm trying to make a symlink for a steam game saves dir to my documents dir which I'm backing up (and want these saves there). Running Windows 10 10.0.18363

Running CMD in admin mode with the following command

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\mpw\Documents\Evil Genius saves" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Evil Genius\DynamicResources\Layouts"
```

Returns the error: "The system cannot find the file specified."

I can create a symlink to other locations for this target directory without issue. Can anyone shed light on what's going on here, thanks

Comment: As below: After doing more reading I found it was windows defender blocking the action. I was stumped at first because by all accounts in the documentation the command was correct. Go into windows security -> virus & threat protection -> protection history -> "protected folder access blocked" - allow this action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For use `mklink` in you `Windows`, read the information on [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) about.

[Elevation](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)

- By default, only **Administrators** can create *symbolic links*. The security setting 'Create symbolic links' can be granted at: `Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\*`
- Creating a symbolic link requires **elevation**, but from **Windows 10 build 14972**, symlinks can be created without needing to elevate the console as administrator - this does however **require** that you have **Developer Mode enabled.**

So, you can enable **Developer Mode enabled**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I prefer to apply a boot after any changes made to the system settings, this is my habit, so I restarted and typed:

```py
C:\Users\ecker>mklink /D "%userprofile%\Documents\Call of Duty Black Ops II Saves" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Call of Duty Black Ops II\players"
symbolic link created for C:\Users\ecker\Documents\Call of Duty Black Ops II Saves <<===>> C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Call of Duty Black Ops II\players
```

```py
C:\Users\ecker>mklink
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    Specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  Specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```

**Obs.:** You can also activate Developer Mode for Windows 10 using **[PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Enable-developer-mode-27008e86)**, also for cmd command line or batch file:

```py
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "1"
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[MkLink /ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)**

  [√] **[MkLink /MS Doc's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink)**

  [√] **[Enable Your Device For Development /MS Doc's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development)**

Comment: Thank you for the help. After doing more reading I found it was windows defender blocking the action. I was stumped at first because by all accounts in the documentation the command was correct.

Comment: @magnet Thank you too! Good question this one!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that I ran into this issue as well (Windows Defender blocking me from Symlinking documents in certain folders). I used the All-Users Current-Host profile path instead, and that seems to work well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).